# Keil - Configuring Logic Analyzer tool

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, keil, stm32f7

I am working with the Keil compiler in a project using the STM32F769I-DISC1. For debugging I use the ST-Link provided by the board. The idea is to use the on-chip DAC using TIM6 for triggering the output signal.

I need to debug the code and watch the DAC values so I am trying to configure the Logic Analyzer tool inside Keil. I have been looking some documentation but I am still not able to make it work.

I have been working with the ST-Link debugger until now and all the functionality seems to work fine, except the Logic Analyzer.

Here is the configuration:

[image]

and here the Trace options:

[image]

The clock is the same as my CPU clock.

The last option I tested was also to enable the Debug (SYS) from the STM32CubeMX configuration. But Logic Analyzer still doesn't work.

Comment: I've had problems with the Logic Analyzer.  I've gone so far as taking a demo that works with the Logic Analyzer and adding my code to it.  No true success.  I was going to suggest this would be a question for the Keil forums (but I see you have a post there).  I'm interested in you finding an answer.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, could you please send me or post the example code? I am making a review of the code generated by STM32CubeMX and SWDIO and SWCLK are apparently not initialized there (like all other pins used by the Discovery board).